# Override copy files using -exec cp

Tags: linux, bash, copy, exec, cp

```
mkdir zipFiles

find . -name '*.zip' -exec cp {} zipFiles/  \;

Error:
cp: ‘./zipFiles/status.zip’ and ‘zipFiles/status.zip’ are the same file
```

I tried these commands to force copy to override the existing files, but none of them works;

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec cp {} zipFiles/  \;
find . -name '*.zip' -exec cp -f {} zipFiles/  \;
find . -name '*.zip' -exec cp -rf {} zipFiles/  \;
find . -name '*.zip' -exec cp {} -rf zipFiles/  \;
```

Comment: You could simply do a `rm -rf` first, then do the `cp -f {}`  --  If the file doesn't exist in the `zipFiles/` directory ... the `rm` it won't fail.  So it's basically like, "If the file exists already, remove it" -- THEN copy it over ..

Comment: @Zak The problem is that `find` is trying to copy files that it itself has already copied into `zipFiles`. Removing them and recopying them will just produce an endless loop.

Comment: The problem is not that it's refusing to overwrite a file. The problem is that you're asking to copy a file where the source and target is the same, e.g. `cp foo foo` which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `find` to search `zipFiles`. One way to do that is

```
find . -name '*.zip' \( ! -path '*/zipFiles/*.zip' \) -exec cp {} zipFiles/ \;
```

To speed things up, use `-exec ... +` to let `cp` copy as many files at once as possible. Either

```
find . ... -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" zipFiles' _ {} +
```

or, if you are using GNU `cp`,

```
find . ... -exec cp -t zipFiles {} +
```

Comment: Here's is another case, when I tried to copy all shell files to a folder, it is copying without any issues but it is taking more time. Is there any way to copy very speed. Here is what I tried "find . -iname "*.sh" -exec cp {} shellFiles \; "

Comment: Never mind, I got it.  I applied the similar command, it is much better.

Comment: I'm trying to use a backslash on the command bellow at groovy syntax:

find . -name '*.zip' \( ! -path '*/zipFiles/*.zip' \) -exec cp {} zipFiles/ \;
When I try to build this command on a Jenkins pipeline give me an error about this syntax. Even before I do this command have a warning with red syntax on Jenkins form field saying **unexpected char: '\'.**

What could I do for replacing or fix error with this backslash?

    find . -name '*.zip' \( ! -path '*/zipFiles/*.zip' \) -exec cp {} zipFiles/ \;

Comment: Issue fixed by adding one more extra "\"   find . -name '.zip' \\\( ! -path '*/zipFiles/.zip' \\\) -exec cp {} zipFiles/ \\;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rsync command:

> rsync SOURCE TARGET

or

> rsync --force SOURCE TARGET